# How can I make search in files to be triggered on keyboard input in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, findinfiles

Search in files needs "enter" to be pressed. How can I make it scan files after every single keyboard input ??

Also how to prioritize code files, instead of configuration files like .json, that unfortunately pops first every single time in search in files results. Both functions are at default in Brackets, I was hoping to be it working the same in Visual Studio Code. Is there any way to configure it somehow, to make it behave like that ??

Comment: This is known as "incremental search" - I don't think it is supported in the "Find in Files" search panel.

Comment: @Mark This should be default feature, they have it for other inputs, I don't know why it's missing in this case.

Comment: I see there is a `Search on Type` setting that does what you want - but the default is `true` so unless you changed that setting - or it was added since your question, it should be doing the incremental search already.

Answer (score 0):

You can use other search functions, depending on your version.

```
CTRL+P : Quick File Navigation
CTRL+T : Open symbol by name
```

Both of these functions should allow you to search as you type.

Source: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_quick-file-navigation

Comment: It's not searching "in" files.